# Creating a list from a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file called `my_urls.txt` that has 3 URLs:

```
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
```

```
with open("../test_data/my_urls.txt", "r") as urlFile:
    urls_list = urlFile.readline().split('\n')
    print(urls_list)


['example1.com', '']
```

I wonder why `urls_list` is not giving me `['example1.com', 'example2.com', 'example3.com']`

Comment: try `read()` instead of `readline()`. You're only reading one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the open file. This iterates over the lines for you:

```py
with open("../test_data/my_urls.txt", "r") as urlFile:
    urls_list = []
    for url in urlFile:
        urls_list.append(url.strip())
    print(urls_list)
```

Comment: Thank you @quamrana

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 3):

`readline` reads a single line so it cannot give you anything past the first line. `read` could read the whole file and you will then be able to split the result on newlines.

But IMHO, as a file object is an iterable of lines, the Pythonic way would be to use a comprehension:

```
with open("../test_data/my_urls.txt", "r") as urlFile:
    urls_list = [line.rstrip() for line in urlFile]
```

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to iterate over a file as a string...+1

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("../test_data/my_urls.txt", "r") as urlFile:
    urls_list = urlFile.readline().split('\n')
```

Nice try I would say, since you are using `readline()` to read the content of the file, but you are only reading one line.

---

If you want to read the whole file and then `.split()` it in lines, you just have to do this:

```
with open("../test_data/my_urls.txt", "r") as urlFile:
    urls_list = urlFile.read().split('\n')
```

---

You can get the list of the lines in an other way:

```
urls_list = urlFile.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you do `readline()` instead of `read()`. In your example you only read the first line of the file and then close it.

Try this

```
urls_list = urlFile.read().split('\n')
```

It will read the whole file content at once.